# Is there a ruleset for node colors in Neo4j according to their labels?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-node

I have user nodes in my graph and based on various rulesets, user can have multiple labels like active, on leave, terminated, contractor, employee, vendor, manager etc.
in my graph, user nodes are, let's say, orange and employee label got maybe green, active is grey.
So, what decides which color should the user node take? I tried validating in multiple ways so definitely, it doesnt depend on the first label set or the most recent label set.
See the sample from the graph as below.
[image: green user node]
[image: orange user node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, Neo4j Browser utilizes a styling format similar to CSS, referred to as GraSS. Neo4j maintains an internal stylesheet, and the styling specified last within that stylesheet takes precedence when applied to the associated node or relationship.

Let's say we have a node with both "User" and "Active" labels, and our stylesheet looks like this:

```
node.User {
  color: #F79767;
  border-color: #f36924;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  defaultCaption: "<id>";
  caption: "{name}";
}
node.Active {
  color: #C990C0;
  border-color: #b261a5;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
  defaultCaption: "<id>";
}
```

In this scenario, the color specified in the "Active" styles will be applied because they were defined after the "User" styles. However, as the "Active" styles do not include a caption property, the caption from the "User" style will be used.

By default, I Neo4j Browser creates the stylesheet in an alphabetical order. I assume the alphabetical order of styles in combination with some labels not having all style properties is the reason you see inconsistent behaviour.

To check the stylesheet being used in Neo4j Browser, you can simply type the command :style. Customizing styles can be done by creating your own .grass file locally and then dragging it into the Neo4j Browser window.

For further information on how GraSS styling works, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-styling/#grass). (Please note: The documentation incorrectly states that the top styles take precedence.).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I had to do a couple of tweaks to the grass file, and it not only solved my problem, but I also added an enhancement. So now all User nodes are same colored. But I specified the border color different for each label, so it is very easy to identify who is who.